# How to choose size of samples to determine if set contains elements

Tags: statistics

I have sets of elements (lets call each `S`). The elements in each `S` can only ever be `black` or `white`. I also have a test that determines if an element is `black` or `white`, with some false-positive/false-negative rate `FP`/`FN`. Given all that, how do I determine the size of the sample from each `S` that I need to test in order to determine with confidence that there are less than X% `black`/`white` elements in `S`?
Put differently, how to determine the number of elements that need to be tested, given `S`, `FP`, `FN` and `X%`, to allow me state with confidence e.g. "Less than 5% of all elements in `S` are `black`".

I vaguely know this is a ridiculously easy question. I'm a complete loss at statistics, and trying to state what I think my problem is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of determining the sample size to estimate a proportion of the population is a typical textbook example. For example, if we think of each set $S$ as a coin, the task is to determine how many times should the coin be tossed to check whether it is unbiased. Or as another example, if we think of $S$ as a batch of items, the task is to determine how many items we need to sample to measure the proportion of defective items in each batch.

The additional uncertainty in the form of errors when examining the sample makes the problem more difficult. We can simply try to correct the sample at the end, as we know the error rates. I will start with two approaches for determining sample size and propose a simple adjustment for the added uncertainty at the end.

### First Approach

The simplest and most common approach to determine the sample size $n$ is the following; see also [Wiki Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size_determination#Estimation_of_a_proportion). Let $p$ be proportion of black elements in some set $S$. Let $n$ be the sample size. The estimator of $p$ is the sample proportion:
$$
\hat{p} = \text{proportion of black elements of $n$ elements sampled}
$$

Using the normal approximation, $P\%$ confidence interval for $p$ is
$$
\hat{p} \pm z \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1 - \hat{p})}{n}}
$$
where $z$ is the critical value of standard normal distribution. The width $w$ of the confidence interval is:
\begin{equation}
w = 2 z \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1 - \hat{p})}{n}}
\label{eq: 1}
\end{equation}
Half of the width $w/2$ is called a *margin of error*. To obtain the sample size $n$, we need to choose a confidence level, for example $95\%$ giving $z = 1.96$. And margin of error, for example $w/2=0.04$, giving $w = 0.08$. The equation still depends on the sample proportion $\hat{p}$, but we don't know $\hat{p}$. However, the expression $\hat{p}(1 - \hat{p})$ is maximized at 0.5. So, as the most conservative estimate, we can use 0.5 for $\hat{p}$. Solving for $n$ we get:
$$
n = \frac{z^2}{w^2} = \frac{1.96^{2}}{0.08^{2}} \approx 600
$$
Then, if it turns out that $\hat{p}$ is different than 0.5, the margin of error will just be smaller.

### Second Approach

A little more involved approach to determining the sample size $n$ using a computer. Let $p$ be proportion of black elements in $S$. Let $X$ be the number of black elements in a random sample of size $n$. Then $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n, p)$. Suppose we are testing hypotheses:
$$
H_{0}: p = 0.05 \qquad \text{ versus } \qquad H_{1}: p < 0.05
$$

For different sample sizes $n=300, 400, \dots, 600$, the following R code finds the rejection cut-off value $x$ and calculates the probability $\beta$ of rejecting the null hypothesis at level $\alpha$ for a particular alternative hypothesis $p = 0.025$:

```
> n = seq(300, 600, 100)
> x = qbinom(0.05, n, 0.05) - 1
> alpha = pbinom(x, n, 0.05)
> beta = pbinom(x, n, 0.025)
> data.frame(n, x, alpha, beta)
   n  x      alpha     beta
 300  8 0.03406581 0.6628496
 400 12 0.03550590 0.7939723
 500 16 0.03429019 0.8721178
 600 20 0.03195449 0.9196688
```

From the results, we see that for $n = 600$, the test with $\alpha < 0.05$ has probability $\beta > 0.9$ of rejecting the null hypothesis when alternative hypothesis $p = 0.025$ holds.

### Adjustment for Sample Uncertainty

Now to the problem of having additional uncertainty in the form of errors when examining the sample. Let black elements be positive examples and white elements be negative examples. Let $d_1$ be the number of declared positive examples and $d_0$ the number of declared negative examples in the sample of size $n$. Furthermore, let $a_1$ and $a_0$ be the number of actual positive and negative sampled examples respectively. Everything can be summarized in the error matrix:

[image]

Define false positive rate and false negative rate to be
\begin{align*}
f_{1} &= \text{P}\left(\text{Declared}=1 \mid \text{Actual}=0\right)\\[.5em]
f_{0} &= \text{P}\left(\text{Declared}=0 \mid \text{Actual}=1\right)
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
FP \sim \text{Binomial}(a_0, f_1), \qquad \text{E}[FP] &= a_0 f_1 \\[.5em]
FN \sim \text{Binomial}(a_1, f_0), \qquad \text{E}[FN] &= a_1 f_0
\end{align*}
The definitions can be summarized in the following figure:

[image]

Finally, given $f_0, f_1$ and from observed $d_0, d_1$, we get a system of equations:
\begin{align*}
f_1 a_0 + (1 - f_0) a_1 &= d_1 \\[.5em]
(1 - f_1) a_0 + f_0 a_1 &= d_0
\end{align*}

We can solve this for $a_0$ and $a_1$ when $f_0 + f_1 \neq 1$:
\begin{align*}
a_0 = \frac{f_0 d_1 - (1 - f_0) d_0}{f_0 + f_1 - 1} \\[.5em]
a_1 = \frac{f_1 d_0 - (1 - f_1) d_1}{f_0 + f_1 - 1}
\end{align*}

Thus, one way to resolve the added sample uncertainty is to simply use $\hat{p} = a_1/n$ to estimate the proportion of black elements $p$. Then compute the confidence interval for $p$ using $\hat{p}$ and the normal approximation to test the null hypothesis. Or compare $a_1$ with computed rejection cut-off value $x$ from the second approach and reject the null hypothesis if $a_1 \leq x$.

For this to work, the error rates $f_0$ and $f_1$ would need to be very low. If $f_0 + f_1$ is large or close to 1, the calculation of $a_1$ gets very unstable making this adjustment useless.

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote:
$$\text{white=positive} \\ \text{black=negative} \\ K-\text{percent of S which we're searching}$$
In general there is no answer to your question. 
Let's consider dummy classifier that classify every elements as **white**.
For that classifier $FP=0$, $FN=K|S| \ \forall S$ . If you don't have any information about error rates of classifier on some independent set with some data (aka test set) you can't tell whether every $S$ have elements of the same class or your classifier is dummy.

Here let's consider a case if you know error rates and they are in interval $(0, 1)$ excluding boundaries:
$$ False \ Positive \ Rate = FPR = \frac{FP}{TN+FP}<1 $$
$$ False \ Negative \ Rate = FNR =\frac{FN}{TP+FN}<1 $$

**Firstly** we would suggest that $K$ is chosen and we want to determine proportion of classes. 
Then knowing $FP, FN$ we may estimate TP and TN using error rates like so:
$$TP_{estimation} = \frac{FN}{FNR}-FN\\
TN_{estimation} = \frac{FP}{FPR} - FP$$
Let's denote:
$$ E = TP_{estimation} + TN_{estimation} + FP + FN$$
Our estimations are not equal to true values of $TP, TN$ and to satisfy equation:
$$E = K|S|$$
we should add/subtract additional values as weighted sum:
$$TP_{estimation}= TP_{estimation} + \frac{FPR}{FNR+FPR}(E - K|S|) \\
TN_{estimation}= TN_{estimation} + \frac{FNR}{FNR+FPR}(E - K|S|)$$
then you should round numbers so $E=K|S|$ 
Finally you know estimated number of samples in |S| set:
$$ \text{white percent}= \frac{TP_{estimation} + FN}{K|S|} \\ 
\text{black percent}= \frac{TN_{estimation} + FP}{K|S|}$$

**Secondly** about choosing K. 
I may only suggest to choose K numerically. You may try to fix batch step size (ex. 10) and compute proportion for every step according to new added elements. If you reach numerical stability and proportions are close in current and previous step - you may stop here and fix the K. After several experiments for different data you may find average K.